# SLDS Blue Prints for Look Up field

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I am trying to build a  custom look-up component and hoping to build some of my skills working with the [SLDS Library](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/)

But I seem to be completely stuck with making the search results display I have attached my HTML file.  The search results are marked with a comment. I have no problems getting things to display if just use a  basis UL and LI tag but it looks ugly.

When I go to dev tools I can the LI tags in the markup. They are generating as I would expect. But nothing appears on the screen.

```
<!--
 - Created by Brooks Johnson on 7/17/2022.
 -->

<!-- Custom Look Up -->
<template>
    <template if:true={objectApiName}>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                    <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click">
                        <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right"
                             role="none">
                            <lightning-input type="Search" id="combobox-id-16"
                                             value={searchKey}
                                             onchange={handleKeyChange}
                                             onkeydown={handleClick}
                                             onclick={handleClick}
                                             label="search"
                                             role="textbox"
                                             placeholder={placeHolder}>
                            </lightning-input>
                            <div if:false={messageResult}>
                                No Results Found!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Show Results Here -->
                        <template if:true={showResults}>
                            <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                                    <ul class="'slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical">
                                        <template for:each={resultList} for:item='result'>
                                            <li key={result.Id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                                                <div  class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                                                      <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                                          <lightning-icon icon-name='standard:Account' size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                                      </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                                                    <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{result.Name}</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                {result.Name}
                                            </li>
                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </template>
</template>
```